# How to Avoid Duplicate in Set<Object>

Tags: java, set

I have one `Set`:

```
final Set<Object> partialResults = new LinkedHashSet<Object>();
```

Setting values like this:

```
partialResults.add(createResultList(data.getProduct(), data.getMaterialId()));

private List<Object> createResultList(final ProductModel product, final String code)
    {
        final List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
        result.add(product);
        result.add(code);
        return result;
    }
```

It is adding duplicate products; how to avoid adding duplicate records?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Set` contains `ArrayList` instances, each containing a `ProductModel` instance and a `String` instance. In order for two elements to be considered equal by the `LinkedHashSet`, they must have the same `hashCode` and the `equals` method should return true when applied to both of them.

For `ArrayList`, `hashCode` and `equals` depend on `hashCode` and `equals` of the elements of the `ArrayList`. `String` overrides `hashCode` and `equals` properly, which means you probably didn't override `hashCode` and `equals` of `ProductModel` properly.

Comment: I cant override in ProductModel cz its is a autogenerated class from xml file any other way to remove duplicate records from partialResults.

Answer (score 1):

Either do what Eran suggests or (looking at the use case at hand) change your logic to using a `HashMap` rather than a `Set` using the `code` String as key and the `ProductModel` object as value. That way you get a unique collection of `ProductModels` with map.values() and save yourself the hassle of overwriting `hashCode` and `equals` in `ProductModel`.

Comment: so, code is not a unique id of ProductModel - different ProductModels can use the same code?